# Cant deploy "war" file from Virtual Hosts, see a directory listing

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, deployment

This is my httpd.conf configured with Virtual hosts:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://foo.baz.in
DocumentRoot /var/www/foo/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://bar.baz.in
DocumentRoot /var/www/
</VirtualHost>
```

The second virtual host is a Wordpress blog, configured with .htaccess, and index.php in the root i.e. /var/www, and rest of the files in wordpress's own folder.

However, the first virtual host is a "war" file, and when I goto `foo.baz.in`, I see the directory listing, containing the war. I also tried changing the `DocumentRoot` to /var/www/foo/foo.war` but I get an error

`Restarting web server: apache2Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/foo/foo.war] does not exist`

I also changed the owner and permission of the war to www-data:www-data and changed the permissions to 755, but to no avail.

How do I make apache deploy my "war"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apache doesn't deploy war files.. [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) does. So use that instead.

Comment: yes, that didnt strike me. I configured it with mod_proxy. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Mike's answer which is your fundamental problem, the ServerName directive used for name-based vhosts [among other things] takes a domain name, not a URL with a scheme on it.

Of course this would only get you to your static content, not actually get your EE app working with Apache alone.